# Get length of array property in internal class in C#, or other iteration method that works?

Tags: c#, .net, scope, enumerable, class-visibility

I have a set of C# classes generated by the [json2charp](http://json2csharp.com/) web utility from a JSON response resulting from a REST call.  I use the classes to deserialize future JSON responses into those classes.  Everything works great.  One of the internal classes has a property that is an array.  I tried to use the property in a *for-loop* using the array's **Length** property but the Length property is unavailable in the current scope.  I'm guessing this is because it is an internal class?

To work around the problem I added a public property called **CountBreeds** that just returns the array Length. That works fine.  But I'm wondering if there is a way to get the Length of an internal class's array property without having to make properties just to expose the Length property of the array?  If not, is there a way to iterate the array without adding IEnumerable support to the class?

I know I could remove the "internal" specifier but I'd like to keep it if I can.  Code snippets below:

```
// The internal class I want to iterate.
internal class Breeds
{

    [JsonProperty("breed")]
    public Breed[] Breed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@animal")]
    public string Animal { get; set; }

    // This property was added to facilitate for loops-that iterate the
    //  entire array, since the Length propery of the array property
    //  can not be accessed.
    public int CountBreeds
    {
        get
        {
            return Breed.Length;
        }
    }
} // internal class Breeds

// Code that iterates the above class.

// >>>> This doesn't work since the Breeds Length property
//  is unavailable in this context.
//
// Add the breeds to the list we return.
for (int i = 0; i < jsonPF.Petfinder.Breeds.Length; i++)
    listRet.Add(jsonPF.Petfinder.Breeds.Breed[i].T);


// >>>> This *does* work because I added manually the CountBreeds
//  property (not auto-generated by json2csharp).
// Add the breeds to the list we return.
for (int i = 0; i < jsonPF.Petfinder.Breeds.CountBreeds; i++)
    listRet.Add(jsonPF.Petfinder.Breeds.Breed[i].T);
```

Comment: I see no reason why `Length` shouldn't be visible.. also, array's do implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: A class representing a single breed called `Breeds` and containing an array called `Breed`? Am I the only one who finds it strange? What kind of logic did you use when designing this kind of naming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You weren't asking for the length of the array, but for a non-existent Length property in the Breeds class. Try this instead...

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonPF.Petfinder.Breeds.Breed.Length; i++)
```

Comment: Good catch! Didn't see that one

Comment: Nice! I didn't notice that one either (was just thinking about the `Length` property of an array!)

Comment: Beware the risks of such similar naming. Best avoided, I find.

Comment: @spender - Agreed. However, those names are coming from the JSON crafted by an external web service.  I didn't set those.

Answer (score 0):

Length should be visible. Length is a public property on Array, so it has nothing to do with the internal class.